# AOP pointcut not registering

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a given spring bean with 3 methods, A, B and C. methodA is the entry point, it calls methodB and that method calls methodC.

Here is my bean:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="misc.zombies.Braainns" scope="prototype">
```

And here is my Java class where it runs:

```
@Autowired
private Braainns myBean;

    ...

    myBean.methodA() //remember, methodA -> methodB -> methodC
```

**This point cut does not work, the advice is never applied**

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="deadLockRetry" ref="myDeadLockRetryExecutor">
        <aop:pointcut id="myRetryOperation" expression="execution(* misc.zombies.Braaainns.methodC(..))"/>
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="myRetryOperation" method="retry"/>    
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

**This point cut does work, yet the advice is only applied to methodA**

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="deadLockRetry" ref="myDeadLockRetryExecutor">
        <aop:pointcut id="myRetryOperation" expression="execution(* misc.zombies.Braaainns.*(..))"/>
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="myRetryOperation" method="retry"/>    
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring AOP creates proxies around your bean, so for every method methoda, methodb, methodc, there exists a method methoda2, methodb2, methodc2 on the proxy around your bean.

Now wenn you call `bean.methodA()` from the outside, what the client actually sees is the proxy, so `proxy.methodsA2()` is called, which delegates to `bean.methodA()`. Now if `bean.methodA()` calls `bean.methodB()`, the proxy logic is never invoked, as the context is already inside the proxy:

```
proxy             bean  
methodA2() -->    methodA()
                   |
                   V  
methodB2() -->    methodB()
```

But this is what you want:

```
proxy             bean  
methodA2() -->    methodA()
                     |
   /-----------------/
   |                 
   V
methodB2() -->    methodB()
```

There are several ways to resolve this:

1. By far the best way is to change your design in a way that either:

   - methodA() doesn't call methodB() at all
   - methodA() and methodB() are in different benas, one of which is injected into the other
   - the proxy logic around methodA() is adequate for both methods
2. If that's not possible your options are to either use AspectJ compilation (see [Spring AOP or full AspectJ](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-spring-or-aspectj), [Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj)). That way you are no longer using proxies, but the aspects get woven into your classes.
3. Or violate the AOP principles by making the bean object aware of the proxy around it:

   ```
   public void methodA(){
       ((MyInterface)AopContext.currentProxy()).methodB();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Spring AOP pointcuts need to be declared on interfaces, not concrete classes, as they are proxy-based.

Unlike AspectJ, Spring AOP doesn't compile anything special into your code - instead it supplies a proxy object to any beans that are wired up with the `myBean` bean so that the given advice can be run whenever those other classes call `methodC()`.

Calls to the advised method from within the same class do not work as you are hoping since at this point, `methodB()` is calling the `methodC()` within the same class, and not on the proxy object.

[From the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn):

> Spring AOP defaults to using standard J2SE dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied.

See also the section on [Understanding AOP proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) to understand more.

It sounds like you may be able [to use CBLIG proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-autoproxy-force-CGLIB) instead of the default mechanism if you truly want the advice to work as you have outlined in your question, although I suggest using a pure interface proxy for simplicity - the advice is attached your interface boundaries.

Comment: *I believe Spring AOP pointcuts need to be declared on interfaces, not concrete classes, as they are proxy-based.* The second part is correct and the source of the problem here, the first part is false.

Comment: CBLIG  with `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">` did not get the point cut to register.